# Derivative of Sort

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, sorting

I want to calculate gradient of `Sort[{x1,x2,x3,x4}]` but it seems like I'm getting a wrong answer. Specifically `Plot[Sort[{2, 1, x, 10}][[4]], {x, -20, 20}]` gives me

[image]

while `D[Sort[{2,1,x,10}],x]` returns `{0,0,0,1}`, which is not true.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Since `Sort[{2, 1, x, 10}]` yields `{1, 2, 10, x}` and the derivative of `{1, 2, 10, x}` is `{0, 0, 0, 1}`, I'd say the derivative is correct.  What do you think it should be?

Comment: As for the `Plot[]`, since it holds its argument, it won't sort `{2, 1, x, 10}` and then plug in `x`; instead, it plugs in `x` and then sorts (then takes part 4, which will be the greatest of the four numbers. -- I'm not sure which order of operations (plug in then sort or the reverse) you want.  `Max[{2,1,x,10}]` might be a better way to approach it.

Comment: Derivative is HevysideTheta(x-10) as you can see from the graph.

Comment: Try `D[Max[{2, 1, x, 10}], x]`.

Comment: Max is a different function, which works, Sort doesn't. I need to differentiate Sort, not Max.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Treating `Sort` as a function from the disjoint union of $\bf R^n$, $n=0,1,2,\dots$, to the same union, here is one way to define the derivative. I'll call the numerical sort `NSort`, just so I don't have to overwrite a built-in function.

```
NSort[list_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := NumericalSort[list];

Derivative[orders_List][NSort][list_List] /; Length[orders] == Length[list] :=
 With[{args = Array[Slot, Length@orders]},
  Evaluate@Piecewise[
      Function[
        p, {D[p, Sequence @@ Transpose@{args, orders}], 
         Less @@ p}] /@ Permutations[args],
      Indeterminate
      ] & @@ list]
```

OP's example:

```
df = D[NSort[{2, 1, x, 10}], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Indexed[df, 4], {x, -20, 20}]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
D[NSort[{2, 1, 3 x, x^2}], {x, 2}] // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: COOL! Thank you so much!

Comment: @stiv You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is definitely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/346882), here is a possible solution:

```
list = {2, 1, x, 10};
listDer = D[list, x];

Plot[
 listDer[[Ordering[list, -1]]]
 , {x, -20, 20}
]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems likely but the insistence on avoid `Max` makes me think the OP is interested in other components of the sorted vector as well.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah, probably. That's easy though: just drop the `-1` in `Ordering`. Hard to tell what exactly OP wants anyway.